# GitLab Pipeline trigger: rerun latest tagged pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

We have an app (let’s call it the `main` repo) on GitLab CE, that has a production build & deploy pipeline, which is only triggered when a tag is deployed. This is achieved in `.gitlab-ci.yml` via:

```
only:
  - /^v.*$/
except:
  - branches
```

We also have two other (let’s call them `side`) repositories (e.g. translations and utils). What I’d like to achieve is to rerun the latest (semver) tag’s pipeline of `main`, when either of those other `side` repositories’ master branches receives a push. A small detail is that one of the repositories is on GitHub, but I’d be happy to get them working on GitLab first and then work from there.

I presume I’d need to use the GitLab API to trigger the pipeline. What I’ve currently set up for the `side` repo on GitLab is a webhook integration for push events:
`https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{{ID}}/ref/master/trigger/pipeline?token={{TOKEN}}`, where `ID` is the ID of the `main` project and `TOKEN` a deploy token for it.

However, this will only trigger a master pipeline for our `main` repo. How could I get this to (also) rerun the latest tag’s pipeline (or the latest *tagged* pipeline)?

Secondly, how would I go about triggering this on GitHub?

Answer (score 2):

Either you can create new pipeline specifying `ref` which can be branches or tags, so in this case you need to know the exact tag value https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#create-a-new-pipeline

Or you can retry already the executed pipeline by providing its `id` which you can get from https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#list-project-pipelines by sorting by `id` and filtering by `ref` but it'll give you the last pipeline with a tag `/^v.*$/` which may not match with the specific version you need.

Comment: I think any last run pipeline that matches `/^v.*$/` will suit our use-case just fine; testing it out now